# Can I integrate kivy GUI with django web framework?

Tags: django

I have an app built with kivy GUI library. I want to build a login system for that using django web framework. Can I integrate my kivy GUI with django web framework?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use the rest framework in kivy with Django or better yet, it is very convenient and simple ...